# Should I contact the company directly if the recruitement agent is not contacting me? (UK)

Tags: interviewing, professionalism, graduate, software-engineering

I was contacted by a recruiting agent, who suggested a graduate role and everything went smoothly. Had a telephonic hr interview, a technical online interview, and face to face presentation interview. They all went well and during the last interview, I was told they will let me know either the next day or by the 20th of Sept.

It is now the 22nd of Sept and I have yet to hear anything from them. I have tried contacting the recruiting agent (who works for a different company) multiple times but have been unable to get in touch. This is very bizarre since he was always available for a chat prior to the last interview.

I am considering calling the company (who took my interview) directly to ask for feedback. Would that be considered unprofessional?

I am fully expecting that they did not hire me but I just want to know what actually happened all of a sudden and get some feedback that would help me improve for future interviews.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately it's very common that recruiters will simply "ghost" you when you don't get the job. In my personal opinion that's rude, inconsiderate and completely unnecessary but it happens surprisingly often.

> I am considering calling the company (who took my interview) directly to ask for feedback. Would that be considered unprofessional?

Depends on how you phrase it. If you are polite, point out that you can't get in touch with the recruiter and just want to know about the status, that's possibly ok. Don't expect much of an answer.  I would wait for at least one week after the original date.

> I am fully expecting that they did not hire me

That's a likely assumption.

> but I just want to know what actually happened all of a sudden and get some feedback that would help me improve for future interviews.

It's very unlikely that they would share any actual information. If they say anything at all it will be something boilerplate (not an ideal fit, found a better fit, etc.) . There is no benefit for them to disclose the real reasons and in many legislation there is actual be a legal risk associated.

Comment: Good answer. Only additional thing I want to add: consider whether you want to continue work with a bad responsive recruiter or even work with any external recruiter at all.

Comment: Are there any good recruiters left? Ghosting seems par for the course these days, even by highly reputable companies.

Comment: Yes, good answer! I've been in this situation too, and to confirm, this generally means "no". Previously, I made a point to refuse to work with recruiters that employ this disgusting "ghosting" behaviour. It's so rude!

Comment: Just to add, the company may be reluctant to talk to you if they've signed a deal with the recruiter; such a deal will limit the direct contact they can have with you even if it doesn't require all contact to be through the recruiter. If it's a choice between ignoring you and risking a dispute with the recruitment agent, then they'd rather upset you.

Answer (score 2):

Some of my thoughts as follows:

1. You mentioned that there was a communication gap for 2 days - I would say that a couple of days here or there are always possible. You may like to wait for another couple of working days.
2. It may be too early to blame the recruitment agent. It's always possible that he/she may have some serious personal/family issues.
3. It is also possible that the company has some change of hiring plans, and your recruitment agent may be negotiating with them to help you and him/herself.

If I were in your shoes, then I would wait for around a week and then contact the company.